# Hypothesis Test for Population Mean

Tags: statistics, means, hypothesis-testing

The population standard deviation of tensile strength is **2 psi**. A random sample of 8 fiber specimens is selected & the average strength is found to be **127 psi**.

a) Test the hypothesis that the mean tensile strength equals 125 psi vs the alternative that the mean exceeds 125 psi, use $α=0.05$.

b) Find a 95% lower confidence interval on the mean tensile strength. $$\\$$
This is what I've done so far:

a)

$H_o:μ = 125$
$H_a:μ > 125$

critical value = 1.645

Test Statistic:

$Z=\frac{\bar{x}-μ}{σ/\sqrt{n}}$ = $\frac{127-125}{2/\sqrt{8}}$ = 2.83

Since Z=2.83 > 1.645, we would reject $H_o$. $$\\$$

b) I'm not sure how to do part B.

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part B:

The formula for confidence interval for the certain problem is: $\bar{x}$ $\pm$ $Z(\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}})$.

*Z= $Z_\frac{α}{2}$

= 127 $\pm$ 1.96$(\frac{2}{\sqrt{8}})$

= (**125.61**, 128.39)

Comment: so the lower confidence interval is: 125.61?

Comment: Yes, that's correct